# How do determine the type of data exchanged between client and server from tcpdump output

Tags: tcpdump, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I have been working on a server Projekt and sniffing package exchange between Client and the server with tcpdump. I am having a little problem figuring out/ interpreting the output of the tcpdump. I can't seem to find any meaningful information online. so this is what i have.

I did this after sniffing the package to read it in hex and ascii.

```
tcpdump -nnvvv -XX -i any -r vcs_tcp_noimg.pcap
```

I had this

```
The Server is running on port 6126 and Client port 45852
```

[image]
I know that one marked with Red that is Always beginning witht he Null bytes and then E..N --> is the network IP and others.
The blue ones are the actual message/ payload. The first 2 I cant read so I concluded that the type of `data exchange is Byte`. But the `3 marked Blue`, I can see the paramter/field user and the name. Which are text so i concluded the data type is `Text`.

So in this case can I just conclude that the payload/ type of data exchanged between the Server and the Client is `mixture of text and Bytes`?

To prove my curiosity, I went on to change the `tcpdump` format to -A for ascii Text.

```
tcpdump -nnvvv -A -i any -r vcs_tcp_noimg.pcap
```

Why: because if i do -A and get all payloads as ascii Text, then i can conclude that data exchange type is text, if data is unreadable, then i can say data type is `Byte`

I got this
 Read Marked --> clearly unreadable
 Blue Marked --> Clearly readbale

[image]

And then to my surprise, I got this
Red Marked --> unreadable so --> Bytes
Blue Marked --> readable, even got a link.

[image]

So my Question is.
1. How do I determine the type of data exchange between the Client and the Server?
2. From my research can i conclude that is a mixture of bytes and ascii text?

Lastly What is the difference between [F] and [F.]?
I know that [.] is acknowledgement and [F] FIN. can this be [F.] FIN ACK and does that mean the communication has now ended?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could really benefit from a primer on TCP/IP communications.  You should have a look at the RFC documents (793, for example) that completely explain how the protocol works and how to parse the headers.

Communication over TCP begins with a three way handshake, by RFC, which will be a SYN from the client to the server, a SYN ACK from the server to the client and a final ACK from the client to the server.  This opens two half duplex connections over the IP port pair.

To terminate communication gracefully, the RFC describes a four way close.  One side of the connection begins with a FIN ACK, because each side is always ACKing the current position in the stream.  The other side will respond to this with an ACK to acknowledge the close.  That side can actually continue to send data, but the side that has sent the FIN ACK has already closed its channel, so it may only ACK at this point.  Finally (in fact, there will typically not be additional data going back after a FIN ACK), the other side of the connection will close with the same pattern:  FIN ACK, to which the proper response is an ACK.

Comment: Thanks David for the response. I did that already,  and submitted my research. Thanks RFC is always hepful.